# What is this white flower?

Tags: identification

[image]

[image]
They are not very tall. About 1 to 2 foot tall.

Spotted in Sydney, Australia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be Flannel Flower ([Actinotus helianthi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actinotus_helianthi)). Apparently the Latin name comes from the shape of the flower cluster with bracts resembling the rays of the sun, and the common name refers to the plant being woolly. It is commonly found in the Sydney area and is particularly noticeable in the southern hemisphere in spring.